# Angular 7 with SSR request to wrong API end-point

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am using Angular 7 and wanted to add SSR to the project. My Angular 7 project is serving with default port `http://localhost:4200` and using Laravel with port `http://127.0.0.1:8000`. After I added the Universal command, built it using the command `npm run build:ssr` and serve with the command `npm run serve:ssr`. And it went well without any error. So when I check my console in the browser, It's showing an error because it's requesting the wrong end-point `http://localhost:4000/server/api/theme-page` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/server/api/theme-page`. Is there anything I need to configure or change? I am very new to this Angular Universal. My project working well when I am using the command `ng serve` and get data from the correct end-point. Thanks.

Comment: When you run `npm run serve:ssr` internally it runs `server.ts` on node. I'm not sure, how the same can work on laravel. I think you can visit this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/281) for more info

Comment: What are the values for the `BASE_URL` providers in your `main.ts` and `main.server.ts`? Can you post these files + the file where you perform your http request?

Comment: @Pieterjan main.ts file doesn't have BASE_URL. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: Well I'm trying to figure out where the `http://localhost:4000` is coming from, but without any code that's hard to do. In my case I have a `BASE_URL` provider defined in both my [src/main.ts](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/main.ts#L25) and [src/main.server.ts](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/src/main.server.ts#L35). Next I'm simply injecting my provider in the services: `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) { }`